# Problem when running MVC where javascript files are not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have VS2008 developing a MVC app 1.0.

I have added a .js file to app.

But when I make changes and start debugging the app
the javascript is using previous version and not
my additional changes.

In the debugger the js file has the  suffix [dynamic]
after the name of the file.

What is causing this?
I have asked similar question before but answers don't help.

Malcolm

Answer (score 3):

Browser caches previous version of your js file.

Just hit ctrl+shif+del => enter.

For internet explorer - tools, internet options, delete...

Comment: If you are using visual studio js debugger, try re-running it again. I guess for client side debugging it just copies current state when you start it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Cassini server (the visual studio server with an icon down by the clock)